# If $|G| = 1920$ and $|H| = 80$ are groups, $f:G \rightarrow H$ epimorphism then $G$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, solvable-groups

I have problems proving the following proposition

> Let $G,H$ be groups with $|G| = 1920$ and $|H| = 80$. If $f:G
>  \rightarrow H$ is an epimorphism then $G$ is a solvable group.

I've done a lot of research and learnt a couple of things I didn't know but I have no idea on how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: $G$ has a solvable quotient (isomorphic to $H$), from Burnside's theorem. Then it is sufficient to find a solvable normal subgroup of $G$… think to the kernel of $f$.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the only non-cyclic simple group of size less than 100 is $A_5$, the alternating group on 5 elements, which has size 60?

Comment: Any answer depends on what you know. For example, do you know that every group of order $p^aq^b$ is soluble?

Comment: No, I didn't proof Burnside's theorem yet so it would be better not to do it that way (although it can be interesting to mention it). In fact Burnside's theorem was never proved in my class so I don't think i can use it because this problem comes from an exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: since $\;80=2^4\cdot5\;$ , any group of this order has either a unique Sylow $\;5\,-$ subgroup or a unique Sylow $\;2\,-$ subgroup (why? Count elements), so either way it has a normal Sylow subgroup, and either it has a quotient of order $\;2^4\;$ , which is a $\;2\,-$ group and this solvable, or a quotient of order $\;5\;$ which is abelian and trivially solvable, so the whole group will be solvable.

Also, the kernel of $\;\phi:G\to H\;$ has order $\;24\;$, and also this group is solvable (can you prove it? No need of Burnside's Theorem), so again $\;G\;$ is a solvable extension by a solvable group and we're done.

Comment: is it enough with $\phi$ being an homomorphism? Because then $G/Ker(\phi) \cong Im(f) \le H$ and subgroups of solvable groups are solvable.

Comment: Yes, it is enough.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why is that enough? The kernel can be G itself (if $\varphi$ is trivial). Ofcourse $G/ker(\varphi)$ is solvable, but I can't tell why $ker\varphi$ itself is solvable (without assuming something about $|Im(\varphi)|$)

Comment: @BBLN Nop, it can't be $\;\ker\phi=G\;$ as but the first isomorphism theorem $\;G/\ker\phi\cong H\;$ (it is given $\;\phi\;$ is an epimorphism). And then, as shown, both $\;\ker\phi\;$ and $\;G/\ker\phi\;$ are solvable, so thus $\;G\;$ is...

Comment: @DonAntonio I see. Rodrigo comment confused me, as it sounded like homomorphism alone is enough (not epimorpishm)

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is an extension of $H$ by a normal subgroup of $G, N,$ that has order 24. Both $|H|$ and $|N|$ have two distinct prime factors, so both groups are solvable, and an extension of a solvable group by a solvable group is solvable.

Comment: Nice answer! However, the OP just mentioned in the comments: " I didn't proof Burnside's theorem yet".

Comment: Ah, I'll try to think of another way.